# python pandas dataframe find row containing specific value and return boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I want compare two dataframes which is df1 and df2. df1 is a data that updates every hour by it self. df2 is a dataframe that alreay exists. I want to append specific row that is updated.

for example, Here is df1

df1:

[image: fd1]

which contains 5 rows of information

and df2 which already existed

df2:

[image: df2]

we can tell that eric is added but df2 is not representing that.

I could overwrite df2 with df1 but I shouldn't as there will be remark that will be updated by person later the data is written.

So, I decided to remove each rows of data by finding it from df2 by its id, and remove them with for loop

and after that, there will be only eric's row will remain which will make me possible to just append eric to df2.

So what I tried is this

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    id = row['id']
    if df2.loc[df1['id'].isin(id)] = True:
        df1[df1.id != id)
```

and it returns syntax error....

am I on the right track? is it will be the best solution to solve this problem?and how should I change the code to achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you looking for `pd.concat([df2,df1[~df1.Id.isin(df2.Id)]],axis=0)
`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your code ...

```
l=[]
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    id = row['Id']
    if sum(df2['Id'].isin([id]))>0:
        l.append(id)
l
Out[334]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # those are the row you need to remove 

df1.loc[~df1.index.isin(l)]# you remove them by using `~` + .isin 
Out[339]: 
   Id Name
5   5    F
6   6    G
```

---

By using `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df2,df1[~df1.Id.isin(df2.Id)]],axis=0)
Out[337]: 
   Id Name
0   0    A
1   1    B
2   2    C
3   3    D
4   4    E
5   5    F
6   6    G
```

---

Data Input

```
fake = {'Id' : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'Name' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(fake)

fake = {'Id' : [0,1,2,3,4],
         'Name' : ['A','B','C','D','E']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(fake)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that `'steve'` has a remark that we want to preserve in `df1` and that `'jack'` has a remark we want to save in `df2`.  We can set the indices of each dataframe to `['id', 'name']` and use `pd.Series.combine_first`

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=[12, 34, 56, 78, 90, 13],
    name='james steve jack ted eric bob'.split(),
    remark='',
))
df1.at[1, 'remark'] = 'meh'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=[12, 34, 56, 78, 13],
    name='james steve jack ted bob'.split(),
    remark='',
))
df2.at[2, 'remark'] = 'smart'
```

---

**Solution**

```
s1 = df1.set_index(['id', 'name']).remark
s2 = df2.set_index(['id', 'name']).remark

s1.mask(s1.eq('')).combine_first(s2.mask(s2.eq(''))).fillna('').reset_index()

   id   name remark
0  12  james       
1  13    bob       
2  34  steve    meh
3  56   jack  smart
4  78    ted       
5  90   eric
```

---

However, supposing it was exactly as OP presented it!

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=[12, 34, 56, 78, 90, 13],
    name='james steve jack ted eric bob'.split(),
    remark='',
))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    id=[12, 34, 56, 78, 13],
    name='james steve jack ted bob'.split(),
    remark='',
))
df2.at[2, 'remark'] = 'smart'
```

---

**Solution**

```
df2.append(df1).drop_duplicates(['id', 'name']).reset_index(drop=True)

   id   name remark
0  12  james       
1  34  steve       
2  56   jack  smart
3  78    ted       
4  13    bob       
5  90   eric
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has several functions available that allow merging and joining different DataFrames. One you could use here is `merge`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
>>>merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
    id   name remark
0  234  james       
1  212  steve       
2  153   jack  smart
3  567    ted       
4  432   eric    NaN
5  543    bob
```

If you didn't want the inserted value to be `NaN`, you could always use `fillna`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html.